# Determine infinite sum with shifting binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am looking for a way to find analytically the following sum

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{6^i}
\begin{pmatrix}
i+k\\ i
\end{pmatrix}
 = \Big(\frac65\Big)^{1+k}$,

for some integer $k>0$. The answer I displayed here was found by Wolfram Alpha. I looked at partial sums, but it involves hypergeometric functions. Is there any way around this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$F\left(k+1\right)=1+\sum_{i\geq1}\dbinom{i+k+1}{i}\frac{1}{6^{i}}
 $$ $$=1+\sum_{i\geq1}\left(\dbinom{i+k}{i}+\dbinom{i+k}{i-1}\right)\frac{1}{6^{i}}
 $$ $$=1+\sum_{i\geq1}\dbinom{i+k}{i}\frac{1}{6^{i}}+\sum_{i\geq1}\dbinom{i+k}{i-1}\frac{1}{6^{i}}
 $$ $$=\sum_{i\geq0}\dbinom{i+k}{i}\frac{1}{6^{i}}+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i\geq0}\dbinom{i+k+1}{i}\frac{1}{6^{i}}
 $$ $$=F\left(k\right)+\frac{F\left(k+1\right)}{6}
 $$ hence $$F\left(k+1\right)=\frac{6}{5}F\left(k\right)
 $$ and since $$F\left(1\right)=\sum_{i\geq0}\dbinom{i+1}{i}\frac{1}{6^{i}}=\sum_{i\geq0}\frac{i+1}{6^{i}}=\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^{2}
 $$ we have $$F\left(k+1\right)=\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^{k+2}.
 $$

Comment: Thanks, this is really neat!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Taylor expansion at $x=0$ of
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1+k}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{-(1+k)}{i}(-x)^i$$
which holds for $|x|<1$.
Then note that
$$\binom{-(1+k)}{i}=\frac{(-(1+k))\cdot (-(1+k)-1)\cdot (-(1+k)-i+1)}{i!}=(-1)^i\binom{i+k}{i}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{6^i}
\binom{i+k}{i}=\frac{1}{(1-(1/6))^{1+k}}
 = \Big(\frac65\Big)^{1+k}.$$

Comment: Cool, thanks! Both answers are great.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\ }
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 6^{i}}{i + k \choose i} & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 6^{i}}
{-\bracks{i + k} + i - 1 \choose i}\pars{-1}^{i}\qquad
\pars{~Binomial\ Negating\ Property~}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{-k - 1 \choose i}\pars{-\,{1 \over 6}}^{i} =
\bracks{1 + \pars{-\,{1 \over 6}}}^{-k - 1} =\ \bbx{\pars{6 \over 5}^{k + 1}}
\end{align}